# Can an object know from which object its method is called?

Tags: java, oop, class, methods

In Moritz Haarmann's Blog I found an [example of usage of Bonjour by Java](http://momo.brauchtman.net/2008/12/zeroconf-made-easy-using-bonjour-for-java/). Here is the code taken from there:

```
public class ServiceAnnouncer implements IServiceAnnouncer, RegisterListener {
    private DNSSDRegistration serviceRecord;
    private boolean registered;

    public boolean isRegistered(){
        return registered;
    }

    public void registerService()  {
        try {
            serviceRecord = DNSSD.register(0,0,null,"_killerapp._tcp", null,null,1234,null,this);
        } catch (DNSSDException e) {
            // error handling here
        }
    }

    public void unregisterService(){
        serviceRecord.stop();
                registered = false;
    }

    public void serviceRegistered(DNSSDRegistration registration, int flags,String serviceName, String regType, String domain){
        registered = true;
    }

    public void operationFailed(DNSSDService registration, int error){
        // do error handling here if you want to.
    }
}
```

I have a question about the "serviceRegistered" method. As far as I understand it is called during (or after) registration of the service (and it sets variable "registered" to be equal to "true"). But what is not clear to me is how exactly it is called. Because the service is registered by the method "registerService". This method, in its turn, calls "DNSSD.register". And, as far as I understand, the "DNSSD.register" will call the "serviceRegister" method of the "ServiceAnnouncer" class. But how "DNSSD.register" knows that it needs to call a method of the "ServiceAnnouncer" class? Can "DNSSD.register" know that it is called from a particular class (in this case "ServiceAnnouncer" class)?

Comment: Unrelated but you way want to remove the "I" in front of your interfaces in order to follow the Java coding standard (and for readability for your fellow Java programmers).

Comment: Right, but I wasn't exactly aware of the java coding standards at the time i wrote the code.. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ServiceAnnouncer` has passed itself as last argument of the `DNSSD.register()` method, which in turn is apparently expecting any instance of `RegisterListener`. This way the `DNSSD` can have a direct handle to the `ServiceAnnouncer` instance.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It defenetly makes sence. But I do not understand, why do you say that "DNSSD.register()" expects an instance of RegisterListener? It expect an instance of a class which use RegisterListener as an interface.

Comment: You can also read it as: an instance *which implements* `RegisterListener`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this class is a listener - namely `RegisterListener`. It has been registered as a listener in `DNSSD` by passing itself to the `register(..)` method.

For more information read about the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).